# The import com.android.common cannot be resolved

Tags: eclipse, debugging, android-source

I am trying to debug AOSP through eclipse(under Linux)..But while building it is throwing errors like:

R cannot resolved to a variable
The import android.util.MathUtils cannot be resolved
The import com.android.common cannot be resolved

Note: When I tried to debug sample app its working fine and not showing any errors.

Comment: Are you attempting to compile AOSP with Eclipse? If you are then don't...

Comment: If you want to use eclipse to debug/browse aosp code, please check my answer at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16582112/aosp-and-intellij-idea/19073832#19073832). You will need a shadow dir of aosp tree so that eclipse artifacts don't come in the way of aosp build.

Comment: @EyalBellisha I am getting The import android.util.MathUtils cannot be resolved. Are there any fixes?